# ggmap geocode output = more response missing columns

Tags: r, ggmap

Using R ggmap to geocode addresses using following:

`mutate_geocode(MyAddr, FullAddr, output = "more", source = "google")`

...provided the following response columns:
lon,
lat,
type,
loctype,
address,
north,
south,
east,
west,
street_number,
route,
neighborhood,
locality,
administrative_area_level_2,
administrative_area_level_1,
country,
postal_code,
postal_code_suffix,
subpremise,
premise,
administrative_area_level_3

However, on Friday 7/31 the responses coming back only include:

```
lon,
lat,
type,
loctype,
address,
north,
south,
east,
west,
```

What happened to:

```
street_number,
route,
neighborhood,
locality,
administrative_area_level_2,
administrative_area_level_1,
country,
postal_code,
postal_code_suffix,
subpremise,
premise,
administrative_area_level_3
```

Is this a google api change?

Comment: I'm also trying to find out how to either get these missing columns or extract them automatically from the list format in output=="all", does anyone know?